# Type error: mockReturnValueOnce from jest.spyOn() inferring argument type as void

Tags: typescript, jestjs, backend

I'm trying to mock the return value from bcrypt's compare method. The return type of compare method is a Promise<boolean>. When I write this line "jest.spyOn(bcrypt, 'compare').mockReturnValueOnce()", the argument type inferred to mockReturnValueOnce is being void and not Promise<boolean>. So, I can't mock the return value with this "new Promise(resolve => resolve(false))" because I got a TypeScript error: "TS2345: Argument of type 'Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'".

Thank you.

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import { BcryptAdapter } from './bcrypt-adapter'

jest.mock('bcrypt', () => ({
  async hash (): Promise<string> {
    return await new Promise(resolve => resolve('hash'))
  },

  async compare (): Promise<boolean> {
    return await new Promise(resolve => resolve(true))
  }
}))

const salt = 12
const makeSut = (): BcryptAdapter => {
  return new BcryptAdapter(salt)
}

describe('Bcrypt Adapter', () => {
  test('Should return false when compare fails', async () => {
    const sut = makeSut()
    jest.spyOn(bcrypt, 'compare').mockReturnValueOnce(new Promise(resolve => resolve(false)))
    const isValid = await sut.compare('any_value', 'any_hash')
    expect(isValid).toBe(false)
  })
})
```

Dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@shelf/jest-mongodb": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/mongodb": "^3.6.20",
    "@types/node": "^15.14.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@types/validator": "^13.6.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.4",
    "eslint": "^7.31.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^20.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.3.1",
    "git-commit-msg-linter": "^3.2.6",
    "husky": "^7.0.1",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "lint-staged": "^11.1.0",
    "sucrase": "^3.20.0",
    "supertest": "^6.1.4",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.4",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fast-glob": "^3.2.7",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.10",
    "validator": "^13.6.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dude try this:

```
jest.spyOn(bcrypt, 'compare').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(false))
```

It worked for me.

Comment: This is a possible solution, but the real problem is that VSCode sometimes doesn't infer the correct type when the method has overloads and we can't choose the implementation we want to mock. On this case, we must pick another way to try to mock it.