# Argument of type 'Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'.ts(2345) - mockReturnValueOnce

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, bcrypt

The method **mockReturnValueOnce** is showing **Argument of type 'Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'.ts(2345)**.

I already tried like this:

```js
 .spyOn(bcrypt, 'hash')
 .mockImplementation(async () => Promise.reject(new Error()))
```

looking this [Type error: mockReturnValueOnce from jest.spyOn() inferring argument type as void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68490170/type-error-mockreturnvalueonce-from-jest-spyon-inferring-argument-type-as-voi) similar question, but has no effect.

I noticed that vscode is inferring void for some reason in the method parameter, but I still haven't figured out why

The signature of method:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dvMY.png

It's weird because I already mocked another class in another file and it worked:

```js
jest.spyOn(encrypterStub, 'encrypt').mockReturnValueOnce(new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(new Error())))
```

```js
jest.mock('bcrypt', () => ({
  async hash (): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve('hash'))
  }
}))

const salt = 12

const makeSut = (): BcryptAdapter => {
  return new BcryptAdapter(salt)
}

describe('Bcrypt Adapter', () => {
  test('Should call bcrypt with correct values', async () => {
    const sut = makeSut()
    const hashSpy = jest.spyOn(bcrypt, 'hash')
    await sut.encrypt('any_value')
    expect(hashSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('any_value', salt)
  })

  test('Should return a hash on sucess', async () => {
    const sut = makeSut()

    const hash = await sut.encrypt('any_value')
    expect(hash).toBe('hash')
  })

  test('Should throw if bcrypt throws', async () => {
    const sut = makeSut()
    jest
      .spyOn(bcrypt, 'hash')
      .mockReturnValueOnce(
        // here
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(new Error()))
      )

    const promise = await sut.encrypt('any_value')
    await expect(promise).rejects.toThrow()
  })
})
```

Comment: Why are the mock implementations of `hash` using the `async` keyword? I do not see any `await` in use.

Comment: @morganney I didn't get it. If you are referring in the 2° line where the hash function is async, it's because it returns a promise. So, the await it's necessary to the fuction signature.

Comment: You do not need to use `async` here `mockImplementation(async () => Promise.reject(new Error()))` or here `async hash (): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve('hash'))
  }`. You are already returning a Promise explicitly and not awaiting anything so no need for `async`.

Comment: It's necessary, otherwise `eslint` throws "Functions that return promises must be async"

Comment: No, ESLint a very good library does not do that. Tslint, an apparently bad library does, and does so incorrectly. Like I always say, most of TS is hype at best, detrimental to good JS programming at worst.

Answer (score 2):

I've an alternative, maybe this looks better

```
test('Should throw if bcrypt throws', async () => {
  const sut = makeSut()
  jest.spyOn(bcrypt, 'hash').mockImplementationOnce(() => {
    throw new Error()
  })
  const promise = sut.encrypt('any_value')
  await expect(promise).rejects.toThrow()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve a similar problem by putting a typing in `SpyOn`:

```
jest.spyOn<any, string>(bcrypt, "hash")
  .mockReturnValueOnce(
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(new Error()))
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```js
const hashSpy = jest.spyOn(bcrypt, "hash") as unknown as jest.Mock<
      ReturnType<(key: string) => Promise<string>>,
      Parameters<(key: string) => Promise<string>>
    >;
hashSpy.mockResolvedValueOnce("hashedPassword");
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
const hashSpy = jest.spyOn(bcrypt, 'hash') as unknown as jest.Mock<
ReturnType<(key: Error) => Promise<Error>>,
Parameters<(key: Error) => Promise<Error>>
>
hashSpy.mockReturnValueOnce(new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(new Error())))
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with version 3.0.7 of bcrypt